# Changing the color in tree view when there is a difference of 15 days between two dates in odoo 13

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, odoo, decoration

I am working on changing the color in tree view in odoo 13 for colorize tree view when there is a difference of 15 days between two dates for example
I have this when one is bigger than the other

tree decoration-danger=" (date1 > date2)"

but i need  when there is a difference of 15 days between two dates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should persist a boolean field `diff_15`: True if difference(date1, date2) > 15 and False otherwise, then use this field in your XML to achieve the proper class `decoration-danger="diff_15 == True"`

I hope this can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` and `relativedelta` are not available in the evaluation context.

You can check the [_setDecorationClasses](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/bb20d56db7554a3962a34b8f249d93eb835659f7/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L1015) function documentation on how those attributes are rendered:

> Each line can be decorated according to a few simple rules. The arch
> description of the list may have one of the `decoration-X` attributes with
> a domain as value.  Then, for each record, we check if the domain matches
> the record, and add the `text-X` CSS class to the element.  This method is
> concerned with the computation of the list of CSS classes for a given
> record.

You have access only to the values of the fields and some special variables like `uid`, `active_id`,